# sql : fusion of lines from one table

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have a table like that :

```
idA descriptionsA idB
AA blablaAA BB
AA blablaAA CC
BB blablaBB AA
```

I would like :

AA blablaAA BB blablaBB

I do :

```
SELECT * FROM mytable t1 INNER JOIN  mytable t2 ON t1.idA = t2.idB AND t1.idB = t2.idA;
```

But it return :

```
AA blablaAA BB blablaBB
BB blablaBB AA blablaAA
```

How can I don't create all of this doublon or how can I delete them after?

Comment: why have you got 2 join conditions? surely you just want `SELECT * FROM mytable t1 INNER JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.idB = t2.IdA`

Comment: good question... I don't remember why I did that. I will delete one condition

Comment: I remember ! If I don't put the double condition it returns a lot of wrong lines like that : AA blablaAA BB CC blablaCC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably a less than can sort it:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable t1 
INNER JOIN  mytable t2 ON t1.idA = t2.idB AND t1.idB = t2.ida AND t1.ida<t1.idb
```

Comment: thank you it works ! (but not with a LEFT JOIN, do you know why ?)

Comment: Left join will bring all the rows from the left table and then populate the right with nulls where the join condition is false.
If you need to use left join, you will then need to take the less than condition out the join and into a where clause:

    SELECT * FROM mytable t1 
    LEFT JOIN  mytable t2 ON t1.idA = t2.idB AND t1.idB = t2.ida where t1.ida<t1.idb